# Go: Vendor only specific dependencies

Tags: go

For one of my projects, I need to use the [go-z3](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-z3) dependency. However, it is dependent on the Z3 solver and hence, the documentation asks to vendor the module. However, I do not want to vendor all of the other dependencies.

For instance, after running `go mod vendor`, I have the following project structure:

```bash
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── pkg
│   ├── pkgA
│   │   └── pkgA.go
│   └── pkgB
│       └── pkgB.go
└── vendor
    ├── github.com
    │   ├── golang
    │   │   └── glog
    │   └── mitchellh
    │       └── go-z3
    └── modules.txt
```

where the `modules.txt` file looks something like:

```
# github.com/golang/glog v1.1.1
## explicit; go 1.19
github.com/golang/glog
github.com/golang/glog/internal/logsink
github.com/golang/glog/internal/stackdump
# github.com/mitchellh/go-z3 v0.0.0-20191228203228-4cbedeba863f
## explicit
github.com/mitchellh/go-z3
```

I do not want to vendor `glog` so I tried the following:

1. Deleted `golang/glog` from `vendor/`.
2. Modified `vendor/modules.txt` to be:

```
# github.com/mitchellh/go-z3 v0.0.0-20191228203228-4cbedeba863f
## explicit
github.com/mitchellh/go-z3
```

However, as soon as I run `go mod tidy`, this gives the error:

```
go: inconsistent vendoring in <path-to-project-directory>:
        github.com/golang/glog@v1.1.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
```

Comment: I think vendoring is now all or nothing.  Either all your dependencies are in the module cache OR in the vendor directory.  I suspect the go-z3 recommendation was intended for earlier versions of Go (pre-modules).